# General relativity: The metric outside of $n$ static bodies

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, binary-stars

I know that the space time metric outside of 1 static body is the Schwarzschild metric.  can anyone tell me what is the metric outside of 2 static bodies or 3 or more static bodies? (' static ' mean that all bodies have the same initial velocity of 0 ).

Comment: There is no solution. (Also static does not mean initial velocity of 0, it means stationary and no time evolution).

Comment: Why it has no solution?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3612/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382506/2451 and links therein.