# Stress-Energy Tensor for a Two Mass System

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, binary-stars

I just don't understand this tensor and would like to go through an example with you to somehow make sense of it.

I consider two spheres with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, densities $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ and radii $R_1$, and $R_2$, which are located at coordinates $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$, move on an ellipsoidal orbit around their center of mass with period duration $T_1$ and $T_2$ and rotate around the axes $\vec{\Omega}_1 = \Omega_1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{\Omega}_2 = \Omega_2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ with the speed $|\vec{\Omega}_1|$ and $|\vec{\Omega}_2|$.

How do I now set up the stress-energy tensor? It is not dust and also not a perfect fluid.

If I use the formula for dust, how do I bring the rotation and the ellipsoidal orbit into the equation? Does this even play a role here?

Comment: If you don't understand the energy tensor a time dependend [two body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity) might not be the right place to start, since that's one of the hardest problems in GR. For a black hole the energy tensor is 0 anyways, and for spheres of constant density it's already [complicated enough](http://relativity.yukterez.net/36.html) for a single mass. If you're interested in the orbit the inside of the sphere doesn't matter though if it is spherically symmetric, and outside of the mass the Tμν is 0, the Riemann tensor is more important

Comment: By the way, this question already has an anwer, which is that there is no answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/binary-black-hole-solution-of-general-relativity